# Task and Event in One List

Tags: apex, visualforce, tasks, event, pageblocktable

I want to show tasks and events of a contact in a `pageBlockTable` how can I show two lists in table? 
Below is my Code:

```
public class ActivityHistory_ctlr {

    public List<Task> taskList { get; set; }
    public List<Event> eventList { get; set; }
    public String contactId { get; set; }

    public ActivityHistory_ctlr(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        taskList = new List<Task>();
        eventList = new List<Event>();
        contactId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');   
        taskList = [Select Subject, WhatId, OwnerId, ActivityDate, 
            LastModifiedDate From Task 
            Where whoId =: contactId];
        eventList = [Select Subject, WhatId, OwnerId, ActivityDate, 
            LastModifiedDate From Event 
            Where whoId =: contactId];
    }

}

<apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!taskList}" var="row">
        <apex:column value="{!row.Subject}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!row.whatId}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!row.ActivityDate}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!row.OwnerId}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!row.LastModifiedDate}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Use a wrapper class. want to display task and event in single table?

Comment: yes in a single table. how can I show in wrapper class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably need a wrapper class to do this. For example:

```
List<eEventTTask> taskEventList = new List<eEventTTask>();

for (Task t : [Select Subject, WhatId, OwnerId, ActivityDate, LastModifiedDate From Task Where whoId =: contactId]) {
  taskEventList.add(new eEventTTask(t.Subject, t.WhatId, t.OwnerId, t.ActivityDate, t.LastModifiedDate));
}
for (Event e : [Select Subject, WhatId, OwnerId, ActivityDate, LastModifiedDate From Event Where whoId =: contactId]) {
  taskEventList.add(new eEventTTask(e.Subject, e.WhatId, e.OwnerId, e.ActivityDate, e.LastModifiedDate));
}

public class eEventTTask {
  public String subject { get; set; }
  public Id whatId { get; set; }
  public Id ownerId { get; set; }
  public Date activityDate { get; set;}
  public DateTime lastModified { get; set;}

  public eEventTTask(String sub, Id wht, Id own, Date act, Datetime, lmd) {
    subject = sub;
    whatId = wht;
    ownerId = own;
    activityDate = act;
    lastModified = lmd;
  }
}
```

Here you're creating a new list, `taskEventList` of a custom type: `eEventTTask`.

`eEventTTask` takes in 5 parameters (your fields and assigns them to the key subject, whatId, ownerId etc...

You then just need to query for your tasks and events and add them to this custom list. From there, in Visualforce, you can access them as below:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!taskEventList}" var="i">
  <apex:column value="{!i.subject}" />
  <apex:column value="{!i.whatId}" />
  <apex:column value="{!i.ownerId}" />
  <apex:column value="{!i.activityDate}" />
  <apex:column value="{!i.lastModified}" />
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

**Edit**

Oops. Forgot to add the new eEventTask([...]) in the loop.

Comment: yeah its working but the header are nt coming in table like Subject, due date etc

Comment: @Anzar Great! They won't with Wrapper Classes though. You'll need to add a headerValue in Visualforce. So that'd be `<apex:column headerValue="Subject" value="{!i.subject}" />`. If that helped, mark this as answered so it can help someone else. :)